# setOnItemClickListener on ListView doesn't firing

Tags: android, listview, actionlistener, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I get the list of files of my SD card and display it in the listView like with the help of custom adapter like that:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
            R.layout.file_manager, R.id.checkedTextItem,
            fileList) 
            {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // creates view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_item, null);

            CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkedTextItem);

            // put the image on the text view
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    fileList[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView.setText(fileList[position].file);
            if(fileList[position].icon == R.drawable.directory_icon)
                textView.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);


            // add margin between image and text (support various screen
            // densities)
            int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

            return view;

        }
    };
```

I want to implement setonitemclicklistener or something like that to listen to the detect items click events. My onCreate() method in Activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.file_manager);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fileManagerList);
    loadFileList();
    file_list = findViewById(R.id.filesList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
            //String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt).toString());
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello world!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
          }                 
    });

}
```

My xml of Activity:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout

              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fileManager"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
               >
    <ListView

        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/fileManagerList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_above="@+id/closecalmlayout"      
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>


         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/closecalmlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:layout_weight=".50"
                  android:text="Attach files"
                  />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:layout_weight=".50"
                  android:text="Do not attach"
                   />

            </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my CheckedTextView Activity

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

      <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:id="@+id/checkedTextItem" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:gravity="center_vertical" 
             android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:focusable="false"
             android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
             android:paddingRight="6dip" 
             android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="16dip"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I click on items, nothing happens. I tried to make setOnItemClickListener in the onResume() method, but had the same effect. I also tried onclicklistener - the same effect. What's the reason of it?

Comment: Seems like something in row of list view takes the focus

Comment: Maybe CheckedTextView, try to remove it and see if it works!

Comment: You want to get the on clicked item from the list am i right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that some view is taking the focus from your list view, when you know which view it is, use `android:focusable="false"` on that view in your xml, and it should do the trick.

I tried your code and onItemClicked is being called, this is my getView():

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checked);
        textView.setText("Hello"); //test, you can do whatever you want with this

        int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

        return view;
    }
```

How I set the adapter (MyAdapter):

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, 0, arrayList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(PlayingAroundActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }                 
    });
```

Comment: I tried to do it with my listView, also with CheckedTextView, but it doesn't help...

Comment: android:focusable should not be used by the list view, but on the view in each row which takes focus. What else do you have?

Comment: how can I get know what view is using now?

Comment: as I can see you only have "TextView" and "CheckedTextView" in each row, right? Or do you have anything else?

Comment: I have only CheckedTextView - textView variable....I tried to add  textView.setFocusable(false) and to add equal parameter to this item in xml, but it doesn't work...

Comment: try android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead on on your CheckedTextView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15898/discussion-between-user1512250-and-carnal)

Comment: It works for me man! ANd I also remove android:focusable from your listView. It should only be in CheckedTextView.

Comment: thank you for your partisipation!!! and did you use setOnItemClickListener like at my code?

Comment: second. xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" should only be on root layout, remove it from your checkedtextview

Comment: I did it like you advice, but it doesn't work for me. Did you use setOnItemClickListener in the onCreate() method or you used it in the adapter? or you seted setOnClickListener to the CheckedTextView in the adapter configuring?

Comment: MAN!!!!!!!!! I find it!!!!!!!!!!! I used wrong old xml with my CheckedTextView, where wasn't set an android:focusable...I changed it to the new one and everything become great...!!!thank you for your participation, you helped a lot man!

Comment: Hahaha LOL mate, yeah then U know next time that some views may take focus. Good luck with your project mate :D

Answer (score 0):

> To get the selected item from the list view .

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
            //String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt).toString());
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello world!"+fileList(myItemInt), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
          }                 
    });
```

Comment: I use the same method, you can see it in the onCreate() method of my post. 
it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return **true**; //return true if using ListAdapter
    }

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return **true**;  //return True  if using ListAdapter
}
```