# setOnItemClickListener not responded

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I try to do a simple `ListView` but I can't click on it.

Everything else works fine.

Maybe I am doing something wrong in the `setOnItemClickListener`?

This is my code:

```
package com.roa.demolistview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Project> mProject = new ArrayList<Project>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_listview);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    populateCarList();
    populateListView();
    listClicked();
}


private void populateCarList() {
    mProject.add(new Project("cool car!!", "very nice", R.drawable.coolcar, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!אחלה מכונית.jpg/zoom/cy2g/image_1bj2")));
    mProject.add(new Project("cool poster", "nice job!", R.drawable.coolproj, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!/zoom/cy2g/imagecw0")));
    mProject.add(new Project("Red car!!", "smooth car!", R.drawable.coolredcar, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!/zoom/cy2g/image1y9x")));
    mProject.add(new Project("A ship!!", "smooth ship!", R.drawable.coolship, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!2015.jpg/zoom/cy2g/image_1mk3")));
    mProject.add(new Project("A plain!!", "smooth plain!", R.drawable.cooltransport, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!Transport 3.jpg/zoom/cy2g/image_12gg")));
    mProject.add(new Project("Yellow car!!", "smooth car!", R.drawable.coolyellowcar, Uri.parse("http://roish2.wix.com/roish-2#!/zoom/cy2g/image19cg")));
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Project> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void listClicked() {
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Project proj = mProject.get(position);
            String message = "you clicked on: " + proj.getName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Project> {
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, mProject);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }
        //find the project to work with
        Project currentProject = mProject.get(position);

        //fill the view
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView nameText  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_nameText);
        TextView describe = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_descrText);

        imageView.setImageResource(currentProject.getIcon());
        nameText.setText(currentProject.getName());
        describe.setText(currentProject.getDescription());

        return itemView;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setOnItemClickListener on ListView doesn't firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159043/setonitemclicklistener-on-listview-doesnt-firing)

Comment: There should be the code of your layout, bet that problem is there

Comment: There is a bug with listview. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30565151/4805317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate of `ListView`.

Do like this without `listClicked` method:

```
private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Project> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Project proj = mProject.get(position);
                String message = "you clicked on: " + proj.getName();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: ok, do you see list of Projects and if you see, what's happen when you click on one of the list's items?

Comment: I fined the problem. all I need to do is change the line android:focusable="true" to false in the XML layout.
thank man for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your click method doesn't get called, Update your populateListView() as follows and try,

```
private void populateListView() {
ArrayAdapter<Project> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);


list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Project proj = mProject.get(position);
        String message = "you clicked on: " + proj.getName();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
}
```

Comment: Also as MilanNz said, you have instantiate your list view twice.

Answer (score 0):

ok. thank for all, I found the problem.
all I need to do is change the line `android:focusable="true"` to false in the XML layout

thank to all of you!! :)